# Is there a more efficient way to enable access to RDS database for multiple developer team?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

Is there a more efficient way to enable access to RDS database for multiple developer team?

Having to deal with Security Group every time a new laptop needs to connect to it seems to be an inefficient way of allowing developers get access to a shared resource. Adding new IP addresses to access the firewall seems slow and time consuming.

Was wondering if there are alternatives to this issue. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing a bit more about your setup. Are the developers connecting from a single network/are they all behind the same gateway, or are they all on separate networks. Essentially if you can write a netmask to capture all developers you can write the Security Group rule for that, otherwise you'd need to open up access to the DB and rely on authentication/transport level security (or I suppose put your DB in a private VPC with a public VPN that developers would need to connect to).

Comment: If you end up needing to whitelist individual IPs, writing a short script to automate the process (via `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress`) will be a lot easier than using the web console each time.

Comment: @Brian Thanks! Would it be possible you point me to the specific documentation or provide a aws cli statement so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of scripting the addition of a MySQL security group rule:

`aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxxxxxxx --protocol tcp --port 3306 --cidr aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/32`

Plug in your security group's ID and the appropriate developer's IP address and you should be all set.

More information can be found [in the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html).